# Android Logcat buffer redirect is being duplicated

Tags: java, android, logcat

I want the Logcat to be logging to a file in my application. So I use this code to redirect the log buffer to file (and it works):

```
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/logcat.txt";
    try {
        // This line clears the previous logs
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder()
                .command("logcat", "-c")
                .redirectErrorStream(true).start();
        //TODO execute this once / double check this is active
        //each time this line is ran it will send another dump to the log file, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-f", filePath, "-v", "time", "ActivityManager:W", "InvApp:I", "*:S"});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   Log.w("InvApp", "This is a message!");
```

The problem is every time this line is ran (every time I start up the app) it's like it hooks up to the event so In my log file I end up with something like so:

**Fist run:**

[TIME] InvApp This is a message!

**Second run:**

[TIME] InvApp This is a message!

[TIME] InvApp This is a message!

**Third run:**

[TIME] InvApp This is a message!

[TIME] InvApp This is a message!

[TIME] InvApp This is a message!

...and so on and so forth.

How do I make sure this code is either only ever executed once, or unhook/clear the exec commands?

Comment: Are you sure it is executing multiple times? Are you sure you are cleaning properly the "logcat.txt" file? Perhaps the "logcat -c" command is lacking a "-f /logcat.txt"  argument.

Comment: Yeah run the app once, code executes. Run the app twice the code executes a second time. It seems they are stacking outside of the applications context.